# Delete all rows from a table that are present in a View

Tags: sql, sybase

The queries I would like to perform:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

   INSERT INTO TABLE_B SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 'something'

   DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN IN (
     SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 'something'
   )


END TRANSACTION
```

As you can see, there is a redundant `SELECT` statement in the `DELETE` query that I would like to replace (if possible), thus improving efficiency.

I was thinking to create a View with the rows in the first query and then scan the View with the rows in the second table. If some condition matches, then delete the row from the second table.

Could I get some pointers on how this could be done? If there is anything wrong I am doing, please criticize.

Comment: `DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 'something'` perhaps?

Comment: You can delete from views in quite a few RDBMSes :D

Comment: Your `WHERE COLUMN IN (SELECT * ...)` will not work anyway, unless `table_A` has only one column.

Comment: What does the "view" in the title have to do with anything?

Comment: #Michael, Sorry, I am using Sybase.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Sorry Gordon you are right. I forgot to add that I was thinking to create a View with the rows from the first query and then delete rows from the second table if that row is present in the View.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, I think:

```
delete from table_a
where some_column = 'something'
```

As written, your query would probably generate a syntax error.  The "SELECT *" would return all columns in table_a, and it presumably has more than one column.

Comment: And **IN** Clause is little bit slower.So always avoid to use it.

Comment: @raman, Could you please explain or link the explanation as to why `IN` is slow?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to do joins in the `delete` statement, but you'd need to specify the table from which you're deleting rows:

```
delete table_a 
  from table_a left join table_b on (table_a.column_a = table_b.column_b)
 where table_b.column_b = 'some_value'
```

Comment: Why do you start with `delete table_a`? Also, could I create a View on the result set from the first query and perform a join between the View and my second table? Would that improve efficiency?

Comment: That's how you specify which table to delete rows from. It's part of the Transact-SQL extension to ANSI SQL, supported by Sybase (http://goo.gl/HFdjf).